# How do I change the display of a class using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have this code:

```js
    function show_all()
    {
     document.getElementByClassName('login').style.display = 'inline';
     document.getElementById('button-hide').style.display = 'inline';
     document.getElementById('button-show').style.display = 'none';
    };
    function hide_all()
    {
     document.getElementByClassName('login').style.display = 'none';
     document.getElementById('button-hide').style.display = 'none';
     document.getElementById('button-show').style.display = 'inline';
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
     <input type="button" value="Show login Buttons" id="button-show" onclick="show_all();"/>
     <input type="button" value="Hide login Buttons" id="button-hide" onclick="hide_all();"/>
    </nav>
        <p class="login">Username:</p>
        <img src="un.png" class="login"/>
        <p class="login">Password:</p>
    <p>Something not ment to be hidden.</p>
        <img src="pass.png" class="login"/>
```

And I need the entire class to be shown/hidden;
I have about 50 blocks with elements with the class "login" and I would like to use only JavaScript to display it.

Comment: will a jquery answer do?

Comment: As per @AnujaAgarwal, a jquery solution is still javascript though it introduces a new dependency. That said, the solution is a few lines of code and would be worth the adoption of the library.

Comment: it's not ajax or jquary...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used an offline version of jQuery instead.

Answer (score 5):

Show:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".login").forEach(a=>a.style.display = "initial");
```

Hide:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".login").forEach(a=>a.style.display = "none");
```

Answer (score 3):

A bit late now but this gets some views.  Why not:

```
var arrayOfElements=document.getElementsByClassName('login');
var lengthOfArray=arrayOfElements.length;

for (var i=0; i<lengthOfArray;i++){
    arrayOfElements[i].style.display='inline';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Changing `display` of every element is bad idea. Just toggle class of all these `login`s wrapper and set `display` in CSS.

Answer (score 2):

A suggestion, why not use JQuery. It's quite simple and easy, style can be none/inline/block etc

```
$('.className').css('display','style');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change the CSS rule after finding it using a function like

```
function findCssRule(selector){
    var sheet;
    var list;
    var rule;
    var sheets = document.styleSheets;

    if(sheets) {
        for(var i = 0; sheet = sheets[i++]; ) {
            list = sheet.cssRules || sheet.rules;   // sheet.rules in IE;
            for( var j = 0; j < list.length; ++j) {
                rule=list[ j]
                if(rule.type != 1)  // styleRule
                    continue;
                if(rule.selectorText != selector)
                    continue;
                return rule;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

and applying it like

```
 if(rule = findCssRule(".login"))
     rule.style.display = 'none';  // or whatever it needs to be.
```

I haven't noticed other people doing this kind of thing so please check it before use. The approach of @br3t 's response is much more usual.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem and after having almost no experience with JavaScript, made up this solution in a day. So if there is something wrong with it, please note and comment. I found out the `getElementsByClassName()` method, which returns an array-like collection object of all child elements that have all of the given class names, more on [getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName). Also, I wanted to be able to do it from one button, so it might depend if you want two buttons to hide or show. You could do it with `classList.add()` and `classList.remove()`.

Create a CSS class:

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

Then with this function target your HTML elements by class:

```
function toggleComments() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("comment");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].classList.toggle("hidden");
    }
}
```

The for-loop is used to get all the elements with this class and using classList.toggle to toggle the .hidden class for them.

You could also use `querySelectorAll()` which returns all elements in the document that match specified CSS selector paths.

Instead of a for-loop, another option is `forEach()`:

```
function toggleComments() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".comment");
  elements.forEach(element => element.classList.toggle("hidden"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function show_all()
    {
 $('.login').css('display','block');
     document.getElementById('button-hide').style.display = 'inline';
     document.getElementById('button-show').style.display = 'none';
    };
    function hide_all()
    {
     $('.login').css('display','none');
     document.getElementById('button-hide').style.display = 'none';
     document.getElementById('button-show').style.display = 'inline';
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
     <input type="button" value="Show login Buttons" id="button-show" onclick="show_all();"/>
     <input type="button" value="Hide login Buttons" id="button-hide" onclick="hide_all();"/>
    </nav>
        <p class="login">Username:</p>
        <!--<img src="un.png" class="login"/>-->
        <p class="login">Password:</p>
    <p>Something not meant to be hidden.</p>
        <!--<img src="pass.png" class="login"/>-->
```

Comment: I dint think so PO asking for jquery solution not even tagged Jquery

Comment: well, I did ask him about it in the comments first and he hadn't replied so I posted it anyways in case he replies yes. I he wants to use jQuery then it's very short answer and he is free to use it.

Comment: as he said earlier he has 50 elements with this class, I think it's better then running two `for` loops.

Comment: if his not using jquery library then for this single line he need to add jquery plugin and answer should be in way which po asking if user asking in java and answer is in C# do you feel its okay ?

Comment: well as I said it's his choice. if he doesn't want to use it, he is free to explore other answers. I'm not gonna force him to use jQuery. why do you keep complaining about it.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this issue as well. Using jQuery can really help remove the monotony of using Id tags or a custom javascript function.

All you need to do is add the class to each element and then use a single line of jQuery inside a javascript function to either hide or show those classes.

HTML:

```
<div class="example"><p>Hide me</p></div>
<button ... onclick="exampleClick()">Click to Hide</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function exampleClick() {
jQuery(".example").hide();
}
```

Comment: Besides your answer would work in a proper conext, it is explicit on a question's title and in a comment that it needs Javascript, not jQuery .